# How do I identify a tab in Magento?

Tags: magento

I want to replace the template for the Comments History tab of the Sales - Order View section of Magento's admin.  How do I identify the tab and correctly reference it?

I was able to replace the template for the Comments History section of Information tab in the Order View by using the following layout update:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_history">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>popcap/sales/order/view/history.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

I've been using Alan Storm's LayoutViewer module (http://alanstorm.com/2005/projects/MagentoLayoutViewer.tar.gz) to get this far, but I just can't figure out the correct reference path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is turn on the template hints for the admin area by executing the following query against the magento db

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints', 1), ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);
```

You'll then be able to determine the relevant template to override.

In this case it's /adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/history.phtml

Don't forget to turn the hints off...it makes it quite hard to navigate around the admin area

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE path like 'dev/debug/template_hints%';
```

Comment: Thank you.  I know which template it is, but I can't figure out how to target it with a layout update.  Do you know what my XML should look like?

Comment: From what I can see, the only (proper) way to change the layout of the tab is to do so by overriding the Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Tab_History class.

In the _construct method of this class, it's setting the template, so you could just inherit the original class and change this part.

Comment: Darn.  I was hoping to use only layout updates.  But I guess if I'm replacing the tab, there's no harm in overriding it.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I tried every which way I could think of...but this was the only one that worked :(